# Get information from resource Android in adapter

Tags: android, resources, listener, adapter

I'm setting some buttons for playing sounds
How can I grab raw resource name and use it as button text?.

This is the resource array :

```
int[] rawMp3 = {
        R.raw.mp3_1,
        R.raw.mp3_2,
        R.raw.mp3_3
};
```

This is inside the getView

```
    btn.setText(rawMp3[position]);
    btn.setId(position);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new BotonitoOnClickListener(position));
```

It sets button text as RES instead of mp3_1 ... That's one thing I need to fix.

In the other hand. I have this custom Listener :

```
class BotonitoOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private final int position;

    public BotonitoOnClickListener(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,resID);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

How can I get the resID ? from the position resource?

Thanks! in advance!

Comment: You can get resource id's using getIdentifier()

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onClick(View v)
{ 
    int pos = v.getId();
    int resId = rawMP3[pos];
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,resId);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```